# Split a column of two attributes into two different columns

Tags: r

I have the following date frame, Ward1,

| Check_In Date & Time |
| --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:18 |
| 2019-01-07 00:11:37 |
| 2019-01-09 00:21:33 |

I want to separate the two attributes to get

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 00:05:18 |
| 2019-01-07 | 00:11:37 |
| 2019-01-09 | 00:21:33 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, Date_Time, into =  c('Date', "Time"), sep='\\s+')
#       Date     Time
#1 2019-01-01 00:05:18
#2 2019-01-07 00:11:37
#3 2019-01-09 00:21:33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `strsplit` and `rbind`

```
setNames(
  data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      strsplit(df$Date_Time, "\\s+")
    )
  ),
  c("Date", "Time")
)
```

which gives

```
        Date     Time
1 2019-01-01 00:05:18
2 2019-01-07 00:11:37
3 2019-01-09 00:21:33
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date_Time = c("2019-01-01 00:05:18", "2019-01-07 00:11:37", 
"2019-01-09 00:21:33")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```